# Qt: Print raw text

Tags: c++, linux, qt, printing, zebra-printers

I need to output a ZPL script to a Zebra printer in a Qt application.
The printer is on a smb share network configured as *raw printer* in the client computer.

Everything goes fine if I call `cupsPrintFile( "printer_name", "./tmp_print_file.zpl", "", 0, NULL )` from a C++ test program.

If I use `QTextDocument::print()` using the same text in "./tmp_print_file.zpl" as document, nothing gets printed.
I sniffed the network and found that the data being sent to the printer server *is not* raw data, but, a postscript!

Is there any way to get the data sent to the printer with no modification at all?

- Let me be clear that I don't want to *render* a text, but just send the label script, that is ready to print, directly to the printer, that understands the ZPL protocol.

Thanks for all.

---

EDIT:

As @Martin said, I tried:

```
printer.setOutputFormat( QPrinter::NativeFormat );
QTextDocument   *doc = new QTextDocument( QString( label ), this );
doc->print( &printer );
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I start, must thank Dave. His suggestion to bypass the temporary file while printing with CUPs works fine.

Now, my conclusion: There is no easy way to print raw data using Qt only.
Maybe creating custom `QPainter` or going down to the bits of QPrinter could give a solution, but it would take me too much time.

The final solution is simply use CUPs API inside my Qt application. Unfortunatelly, it is not portable.

Here is a snippet:

```
#include    <cups/cups.h>

//...

int print_label( const char *text, const char *printer_name, const char *job_name )
{
    int jobId = 0;

    jobId = cupsCreateJob( CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, printer_name, job_name, 0, NULL );

    if ( jobId > 0 )
    {
        qDebug( ) << "Printing job #" << jobId << " (\"" << job_name << "\").";

        const char* format = CUPS_FORMAT_TEXT;  // CUPS_FORMAT_POSTSCRIPT;

        cupsStartDocument( CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, printer_name, jobId, text, format, true );
        cupsWriteRequestData( CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, text, strlen( text ) );

        cupsFinishDocument( CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, printer_name );
    }

    return jobId;
}

//...

// Now, inside any Qt function (may be a slot):

QPrinter printer;

QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog( &printer, this );
dialog->setWindowTitle( tr( "Zebra label" ) );
if ( dialog->exec( ) != QDialog::Accepted )
    return;

    // This is the sample label. Can be anything.
const char  label[] =
    "^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR4,4^MD0^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ\n"
    "^XA\n"
    "^MMT\n"
    "^LL0600\n"
    "^PW900\n"
    "^LS0\n"
    "^BY2,3,54^FT24,109^BCN,,Y,N\n"
    "^FD>;43210000>773>0000^FS\n"
    "^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ\n";

    // Informative only.
ui->txtLabelScript->setPlainText( label );

    // Call the printing function.
if ( print_label( label, printer.printerName( ).toAscii( ), "Zebra_Label" ) == 0 )
    qDebug( ) << "CUPS Error: " << ippErrorString( cupsLastError( ) );
```

And it's done.

Don't forget to link libcups (`-lcups`).

I still hope any buddy to add another solution prooving that Qt-only is possible. Meanwhile, it is enough.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Depends on how you define portable. It certainly isn't pure QT. In my mind that doesn't necessarily mean non portable. This doesn't use os/device specific api calls. It use two multi-platform frame works QT and CUPS.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just do exactly what you did in your test program:

- Create a temporary file (`QTemporaryFile`).
- Send the contents to the file.
- Call your `cupsPrintFile` method.

Or there is probably a way with the CUPS API to bypass the temporary file. *Disclaimer: I have absolutely no experience with the CUPS API; this is just based on a cursory look at some online documentation.* Looks like perhaps the following sequence:

- cupsCreateJob > cupsStartDocument > cupsWriteRequestData > cupsFinishDocument

If that works, you just need to convert your `QString` to the correct byte encoding.

Comment: Of course this should work, but will not answer my question: how to do this in Qt. I'll investigate your suggestion on how to bypass the temp file. Really thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your question then. The way I'm using Qt, it is just a C++ framework--a full application may use not only Qt but many other third-party libraries (Boost, etc.). There's no need to go through Qt if you can already do it in C++. Is there a particular reason you *need* to do this through the Qt API and not just directly in C++?

Comment: It works. I got to print from memory, without any temporary file, as @Dave suggested. I'll search a little more for a Qt only solution (hopefully portable). If I fail, this will be the response.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for fljx's code, it is very useful for me.

I changed a litte for sending raw text to zebra printer .

const char* format = **CUPS_FORMAT_RAW**;

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [QPrinter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html),

QTextDocument is designed to render formatted text.

Comment: All right. *What* should I look for in QPrinter? The only way I see to send data to a printer through QPrinter is using a QPainter and it will *render* my text instead of sending raw data. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you just set outputformat=NativeFormat and it sends straight to the printer?

Comment: `outputformat=NativeFormat` didn't work. I've already tried it and believe that this must have been the right way. Unless I have done it very wrong, this is not a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `NativeFormat` in the context of QPrinter means, that the method of the native printing system is used, i.e. on Windows this would GDI. This does not mean to denote the native method of the printer itself.